# Sitecore HTML Editor Removing onClick events from hyperlinks

Tags: html, configuration, sitecore, editor

Currently when we use the HTML Editor in Sitecore, if I put an onClick event in an `<a>` tag, when I save the code the onClick event is removed. The only way I can put an onClick event in an `<a>` tag is to switch to raw values. Obviously, though, as soon as someone else opens the content item in the editor, my onClick event will be removed.

Can Sitecore be configured to NOT remove onClick events from `<a>` tags on save? If so, where/how?

Comment: just reread this and it's a little confusing because the SO editor removed my bracket a bracket when referring to A tags

Answer (score 1):

By default the Rich Text Editor removes all scripts. This can be disabled by changing the setting:

```xml
<setting name="HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts" value="true"/>
```

Change that setting to false in a patch file and the editor will stop removing scripts on save.

Comment: How do achieve this thing?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. The config file is located here: C:\inetpub\wwwroot{yourwebsite}\Website\App_Config\Sitecore.config. 
    `<setting name="HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts" value="true"/>`

I changed it from true to false.